# Define methods on mongoose Model, like you do on Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know you can define methods on the schema

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({});
schema.methods.method = function(){}
```

But is there a way define methods on the model

```
var model = mongoose.model('entities', schema);
model.methods? = ? function?(){}?
```

Basically I want to write some wrappers that I can use like so:

```
User.findByUsername('me', function(err, user){...});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have **statics** and **instance** methods.
In your particular case, you need to define **static methods** :

```
schema.statics.method = function(){}
```

Have a look on the doc here : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods